# EF6 Create Custom Primary key and no ID column (with Azure Mobile Service)

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, primary-key

I'm creating an Azure Mobile Service using Entity Framework Code First and trying to follow the [Class]Id naming convention for Keys. My goal is to have the [Class]Id column be the sole Primary Key and not have any Id column created.  I can't seem to get that to happen.  When I scaffold a new Azure Table Controller from the following, the generated code creates ClientId, but also creates Id.  When I test the code I get the error "Unable to determine composite primary key ordering..." because (I assume) I'm not addressing the Column Order of Id since it doesn't even appear in the Class.

```
public class Client: EntityData
{
    // Unique ID of this client (PK)       
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }

    (...)
}
```

Not sure it's relevant, but note that I am setting the value of ClientId and not asking the db to auto-set it for me.

What have I missed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Client` class is inheriting from `EntityData` which already contains a Primary Key called Id

```
Public class EntityData : ITableData
{
    [Key]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //Other system properties
 }
```

You could remove the EntityData and setup your own keys etc but you may run into more problems than its worth with `Azure Mobile Services`